# Regular Expressions to remove unnecessary HTML tags

Tags: html, ruby, regex

I have many HTML files that have a lot of unnecessary tags like this.

```
<span class="foo">A</span><span class="foo">B</span><span class="foo">C</span>...
```

I'm trying to remove this series of unnecessary tags and change them like this.

```
<span class="foo">ABC</span>
```

I used a simple regular expression in Ruby.
`myhtml.gsub!(/<\/span><span class=".*?">/,"")`

so far it worked well, but now I have a problem about tags like this:

```
<span class="foo">A</span><span class="bar">B</span><span class="foo">C</span>
```

my regular expression also removes necessary tags such as `<span class="bar">.`

I think of using capturing group like this
`<span class="(.+?)">(.+?)<\/span><span class="\1">`...
but I don't know how to write it correctly.

How can I rewrite regular expression to solve it?

Edit: Thank you for your comment ,but sorry for lack of information,

1. There are many class like "foo","bar","hoge","abc"...etc
2. I can't expect what class consecutive tags have.
3. Also, I cant' expect how many consecutive tags there in each html files

Comment: So basically you are trying to remove the tags with the same css class and if the tag is same and occurring continuously.

Comment: You might be able to use https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize

Answer (score 3):

Best use `nokogiri`

Remove tags

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(string)
doc.search("span.foo").remove
doc.to_html
```

Merge consecutive tags

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(string)
doc.search("span.foo + span.foo").each do |each|
  each.previous_element.inner_html += each.inner_html
  each.remove
end
puts doc.to_html
```